# Not Enough Space

Tags: watson-studio

I've been trying to get IBM Watson Studio to load, but I keep getting the "Not Enough Space" message box stating that it needs 7.5GB of space. I have >200GB of free space and have troubleshooted on my end (disk cleanup, etc). Is there a known issue with Windows 10 or is there something else I should do?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the log file, the path wasn't created on my local machine. Set Path= .../WMIC.exe corrected the issue